# Revolution R: installation on debian jessie

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, debian, revolution-r

I need to install [Revolution R](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/rro/installation/#revorinst-lin) on a Debian Jessie (version 8, 64-bit).

On my system there is already installed [R 3.1.1](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/r-base) and [Rstudio](https://www.rstudio.com/).

The [Revolution download page](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/download/#download) give me three installation package for Ubuntu: 12, 14, 15 (older LTS, current LTS, current version). Rstudio package give instead a single package for both Ubuntu 12.04+ and Debian 8+ (32 and 64-bit versions).

There is a way to understand what is the right package to install?

EDIT: I see from the [community group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rropen/debian$20ubuntu/rropen/B9xDsJJpRMY/lzq0qb0K9QkJ) that Debian is not officially supported, but should be OK using an Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems OK to install Revolution R on Debian Jessie.

Some precautions:

- On my system there is `libjpeg8` as missing dependency. To avoid this, I installed from `testing` repository.

  1. I tried to install the package using `gdebi` to install and resolve all necessary dependencies.
  2. `libjpeg8` is missing from stable repository, so I take it from testing repository, protecting other packages with [`pinning` preferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences):

     ```
     sudo printf "# testing\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

     sudo vim /etc/apt/preferences
     # old
     Package: *
     Pin: release o=Debian,a=stable
     Pin-Priority: 980

     Package: *
     Pin: release a=jessie-backports
     Pin-Priority: 900

     # new 
     Package: libjpeg8 
     Pin: release o=Debian,a=stretch 
     Pin-Priority: 990
     ```

  Note: The installed package is the `libjpeg8:i386` version.
- the installation process of Revolution R **erases** the original `R` and `Rscript` executables, so in my opinion it's better backup them (as root or using `sudo`):

  ```
  sudo cp -i /usr/bin/Rscript /usr/bin/Rscript-original
  sudo cp -i /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/R-original
  ```
- Just in case you need to restore the original `R` and `Rstudio` executables without a backup, should be enough to reinstall the `r-base-core` package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get --reinstall install r-base-core -V
  ```
- using Revolution R with Rstudio should be fine. However if you would use a custom version of R (the original one, e.g.) with Rstudio it's possible to follow [these instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R):

  ```
  export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R-original
  echo "export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R-original" >> ~/.profile
  source ~/.profile
  # logout and login again to use this profile also outside the bash
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the only solution I found. Have to mention that I have tried with Ubuntu 15 version and worked. Also have to install libjpeg8 as showed, but run an apt-get update after step 2. Then to install the package use gdebi MRO-3.2.3-Ubuntu-15.4.x86_64.deb